# summarizing text data from columns to rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data in the below mentioned format:
[Format in which i have data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnm87.png)

But i wants to convert it into the below mentioned format:
[format to which i convert the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOA3Y.png)
I checked the questions asked before they are more related to pivot and unpivot this is also a pivot but conditional and i dont know how to do it in excel, while i don't know any programming language. While the number of records is more than 10,000 thats why i cannot do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *input* and *output* ranges are located at `B6:H27` and `J11:Q27` respectively *(update ranges in formulas as required)*

Try these formulas:

**Household ID** : Enter this `FormulaArray`, to extract unique items, in `J7` and copy till last record
*(Formulas Array are entered by pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously)*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$6:$B$27,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(J6:J$6,$B$6:$B$27),0)*1),"")
```

**Household Head Name** : Enter this `FormulaArray`, to extract Head Name corresponding to Household ID, in `K7` and copy down till last record

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$6:$D$27,MATCH($J7&"Head",$B$6:$B$27&$G$6:$G$27,0),0),"")
```

**Spouse Name** : Enter this `FormulaArray`, to extract Spouse Name corresponding to Household ID, in `L7` and copy down till last record

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$6:$D$27,MATCH($J7&"Spouse",$B$6:$B$27&$G$6:$G$27,0),0),"")
```

**Marital Status** : Enter this `FormulaArray`, to extract Marital Status corresponding to Household ID, in `M7` and copy down till last record

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$6:$E$27,MATCH($J7&"Head",$B$6:$B$27&$G$6:$G$27,0),0),"")
```

**Women Head of Household** : Enter this `FormulaArray`, to validate gender of Head Name, in `N7` and copy down till last record

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX($H$6:$H$27,
MATCH($J7&"Head",$B$6:$B$27&$G$6:$G$27,0),0)="Female","Y","N"),"")
```

**Number of Male under 18** : Enter this Formula in `O7` and copy down till last record

```
=IF(EXACT($J7,""),"",
COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$27,$J7,$H$6:$H$27,"Male",$F$6:$F$27,"<18"))
```

**Number of Female under 18** : Enter this Formula in `P7` and copy down till last record

```
=IF(EXACT($J7,""),"",
COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$27,$J7,$H$6:$H$27,"Female",$F$6:$F$27,"<18"))
```

**Family Size** : Enter this Formula in `Q7` and copy down till last record

```
=IF(EXACT($J7,""),"",COUNTIF($B$6:$B$27,$J7))
```

[image]